# Solving $\| \mathrm a x + \mathrm b \| = y$ for $x$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve equations of the form

$$\| \mathrm a x + \mathrm b \| = y$$

for $x$? $\mathrm a$ and $\mathrm b$ are vectors and $x$ and $y$ are scalars.

Comment: Depends on the norm you are taking. Which norm are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(\mathrm a x + \mathrm b)\cdot(\mathrm a x + \mathrm b)=y^2 \\
x^2 \|\mathrm a\|^2+2x( \mathrm a \cdot \mathrm b )+\|\mathrm b\|^2 = y^2
$$
It's a quadratic equation in $x$.